# ExtractTextPlugin: How do I avoid having CSS Keyframes renamed?

Tags: webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

> If two animations are defined in one file, this file is then included in another two files, animations get the same single letter name a which breaks one of them with lower priority (because the latter overrides the former)

Source: [css-loader issue on Github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/89#issue-91224108%20css-loader%20Github%20issue)

I see the same effect when using `ExtractTextPlugin` with `css-loader`. Several different keyframes from different .scss files are all renamed to `a`. I've tried to disable the minimzation options `discardUnused` and `mergeIdents`, as described in the [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/89). I've even tried to disable minimizing entirely, but that didn't help.

Here's my configuration:

```
scss: {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
                'css-loader?minimize=false',
                /* I've tried these too:
                'css-loader?sourceMap&minimize.discardUnused=false&minimize.mergeIdents=false',
                'css-loader?-minimize',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: {                            
                            discardUnused: false,
                            mergeIdents: false,
                        }
                   }
                }
                */
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        })
}
```

- webpack 2.7.0
- css-loader: 0.28.7
- extract-text-webpack-plugin: 2.1.0

I'm not sure if the problem lies in css-loader or in the way ExtractTextPlugin uses it.
I've been working on this problem for hours. 
Would love to hear if anyone has any helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was another plugin doing the minifaction. As soon as I tweaked the options for `webpack-rtl-plugin` to disable minification, the problem was solved.